# Repeat a method after execution in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, backend

I'd like to call a method again after its execution.

Now I have the method `playSimulation()` which does some calculations and output. After it's executed once I need to repeat it endlessly.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
     private fun playSimulation() {
     // do some calculations
     Timer().schedule(3000) {
                playSimulation()
            }
      }
```

This solution doesn't work, since I get concurrency issues. Sometimes I am lucky and the program runs free of issues but in half of the cases, I get an exception.

```
Exception in thread "Timer-3" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
```

My question is how do I solve the issue and what is the best architectural approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read up on thread-safety in Java. the same techniques apply in Kotlin. You can also use coroutines, but you'll still need to think about thread safety.

Comment: Is that java.util.Timer you are using there?

Comment: Yes it is. I read up on concurrency in Kotlin and found a new feature "newsinglethreadcontext". Trying to figure out how to get it running...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private fun myMethod() {
        
    // do stuff every 1000 milliseconds
       
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        myMethod()
    }, 1000)
}
```

If you need to cancel it at some point, you need to keep a reference to the Runnable and the Handler:

```
private fun myMethod() {
        
        // do stuff every 1000 milliseconds

        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        val runnable = { myMethod() }
        
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
        
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't use the android Handler class. It's not an android application, it's such a backend project.

Comment: Got it! Unfortunately I only know about Android development + Kotlin. Sorry mate!